# PyCharm go to implementation of a method - what does this mean?

Tags: python, c, pycharm, pytorch

I have the following python code:

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
print(t.dtype)
```

Within PyCharm, I select the `dtype` in the last line and go to its implementation:

[image: torch version implementation]

It brings me to this `_TensorBase.py` file, with the beginning that looks like this:

[image: _TensorBase.py]

and the line with `dtype` showing:

[image: dtype line]

Now, this file actually doesn't exist in the pytorch package.  Could someone explain to me what exactly is going when I ask PyCharm to go to the implementation of dtype?  From looking at this, I'm guessing part of the source code is implemented in C and maybe I'm just looking at the interface generated by PyCharm, which explains why the file doesn't actually exist and none of the implementation exists.